# Convergence comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

One of the examples in my textbook uses the comparison

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k} \ln{k}} \geq \frac{1}{k}$$

This comparison is not immediately obvious to me. I can understand that 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \geq \frac{1}{k}$ holds but I would have assumed that by multiplying the denominator of the RHS by $\ln{k}$ the inequality would be reversed.

Comment: Look at $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \ln {k}$. Then examine $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln {k}}$.

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $\sqrt{k} \geqslant \ln k$.

Comment: It is true in fact that for *any* $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists $\;N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;\log n<n^\epsilon\;$ for any $\;n>N\epsilon\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F (x)=2\ln (x)-x $ for $x>2 .$

$$F'(x)=\frac {2-x}{x}<0$$
thus $F $ is strictly decreasing and

$$(\forall x>2)\;\;\;F (x)<F (2)<0$$
then, 
for $k>4$ 
$$F (\sqrt{k})<0 \implies 2\ln (\sqrt {k})<\sqrt {k }$$

$$ \implies \ln (k)<\sqrt {k}$$

$$ \implies \sqrt {k}\ln(k)<k $$
$$\implies \frac {1}{\sqrt {k}\ln (k)}>\frac {1}{k} $$
the positive  series $\sum \frac {1}{\sqrt {k}\ln (k)} $ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the statement that $$\sqrt k \ln k \leq k$$
which immediately follows from the fact that $\ln k \leq \sqrt k$. To show that this holds for $k\geq 4$, define $f(k) = \sqrt k - \ln k$. Then $f(4) > 0$, and 
$$f'(k) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt k} - \frac{1}{k} \geq 0$$
So, $f$ is nondecreasing for $k \geq 4$, and so $\ln k \leq \sqrt k$. This is sufficient to apply the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem.** If $a > 0$, then  $\log (x) < x^{a}$ for large $x$.

It follows that $\sqrt{k}\log k \leq \sqrt{k}\sqrt{k} = k$ for large $k$; then the inequality under consideration follows.